# How can I use mock_open with a Python UnitTest decorator?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest, python-mock

I have a test as follows:

```
import mock

# other test code, test suite class declaration here

@mock.patch("other_file.another_method")
@mock.patch("other_file.open", new=mock.mock_open(read=["First line", "Second line"])
def test_file_open_and_read(self, mock_open_method, mock_another_method):
    self.assertTrue(True) # Various assertions.
```

I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: test_file_open_and_read() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)

I'm trying to specify that I want the other file's `__builtin__.open` method to be mocked with `mock.mock_open` rather than `mock.MagicMock` which is the default behavior for the `patch` decorator. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Should use `new_callable` instead of `new`. That is,

```
@mock.patch("other_file.open", new_callable=mock.mock_open)
def test_file_open_and_read(self, mock_open_method):
    # assert on the number of times open().write was called.
    self.assertEqual(mock_open_method().write.call_count,
                     num_write_was_called)
```

Note that we are passing the function handle `mock.mock_open` to `new_callable`, not the resulting object. This allows us to do `mock_open_method().write` to access the `write` function, just like the example in the documentation of `mock_open` shows.

Answer (score 2):

You missed the parameter `create` from `open` builtin.

```
@mock.patch("other_file.open", new=mock.mock_open(read=["First line", "Second line"], create=True)
```

Comment: This is not required when patching builtins, the docs say "Changed in version 3.5: If you are patching builtins in a module then you don’t need to pass create=True, it will be added by default." I still get the same error.